# how to input data from form and import to pdf and then upload it to database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I got stuck when i try to make a page where i can input data and the data will be import to pdf and then the pdf will be uploaded to the database, how code its gonna be in codeigniter?

I already try code to input data and make it to the pdf and i try  code to uploading pdf but i really don't know when i must Combine of 3 proses, input data> import to the pdf> upload pdf to the database.

Can you give me any suggestions or references?

Comment: you can use `MPDF` to create pdf

Comment: btw Can you give me more specific reference, but anyway thanks. :) @YadhuBabu